# Permissibility of digital art of celestial bodies

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, technology, contemporary-halacha, astronomy

According to Halacha, for Jews, there is a prohibition of portraying Celestial bodies in art, even if not for idolatry. (Generally, for noahides there is some concern, but the rules for what might be considered possibly maybe close to idolatry is less than that for Jews, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/127407/33665)). My question is, does the prohibition on painting certain astronomical bodies apply to digital art on like an IPad etc.?

Comment: Why do you think it would be any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a general rule that everything in the Torah law is what ever is tangible to naked man on Earth. I don't know the shape of Saturn, I just see pictures, photostats. I neither see or feel its form, just see a point of light in the Sky. So no worries of "make no 3d image of things above the heavens" etc.  Flat paintings and flat images, no problem because the verse says "no graven image."

Now what about a hologram, made of light? There's no engraving so I think that would be permitted. If it's not a deity someone would bow to or make an offering to then you have at most a Safek d'Rabbanan if there is any gzera but holograms didn't exist for Chazal therefore you have what to rely on. But if it was a Jesus and someone might bow to it I'm pretty sure that's at least against the spirit of the law. Maybe someone can elaborate with sources, this is the best I know.